# Error with Swift 2: Cannot assign a value of type '[NSURL]' to a value of type '[NSURL]'

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a variable named `downloadedPhotoURLs` that is of type `[NSURL]?`.

I'm trying to assign the results of a function that returns a type `[NSURL]` (non optional).

I unwrap the variable `downloadedPhotoURLs!` when assigning.

I get the error:

> Cannot assign a value of type '[NSURL]' to a value of type '[NSURL]'

I don't see how to fix this.

I'm using the Xcode 7 beta (only because I have to be able to run it on a device but I have the free account)

```
do {
    downloadedPhotoURLs! = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: nil)
    collectionView!.reloadData()
} catch _ {
    downloadedPhotoURLs = nil
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `!`.  Just assign `dowloadedPhotoURLs = try ...`.

Comment: Not just this, also `options: nil` will not work. There's `swift2` tag, so `OptionSetType` is there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems there ...

**Force unwrapping `downloadedPhotoURLs!`**

You can't assign in this way. If variable type is optional, you're assigning to it in a common way, like if it isn't optional, ...

```
downloadedPhotoURLs = ...
```

Unwrapping (`!`, ...) is used when you do want to read / access value. Not when you do want to assign new value. You did it correctly on the line:

```
downloadedPhotoURLS = nil
```

**OptionSetType in Swift 2.0**

You can't pass `nil` in `options:` argument. Signature of this methos is:

```
func contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(url: NSURL,
  includingPropertiesForKeys keys: [String]?,
  options mask: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions) throws -> [NSURL]
```

And `NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions` is:

```
struct NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions : OptionSetType {
    init(rawValue: UInt)

    static var SkipsSubdirectoryDescendants: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions { get }    
    static var SkipsPackageDescendants: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions { get }   
    static var SkipsHiddenFiles: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions { get }
}
```

So it should look like:

```
downloadedPhotoURLs = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(NSURL(string: "")!,
  includingPropertiesForKeys: nil,
  options:NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

More info about [OptionSetType](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html) (introduced with Swift 2.0).